# NgbTypeahead inside the form

Tags: forms, angular, typeahead, ng-bootstrap

I have NgbTypeahead component which uses a list of objects like

```
export class Example {
  name: string;
  value: number;
}
```

as source. It searches by `name`(`value` is used as placeholder in another input). I put it inside the form, set the `formControlName`:

```
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value, myForm.valid)">
         <input formControlName="name" name="exampleName" type="text" [ngbTypeahead]="search"
             [resultFormatter]="formatMatches"
             [inputFormatter]="formatMatches"
              />
<!--..some code-->
      <br><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But when I submit it, the selected object of type `Example` is passed, but if instead I need the value of `input`, what should I do?

EDITED
Removed `ngModel`.

The code of `formatMatches` function:

```
formatMatches = (value: any) => value.name || '';
```

Comment: Show us the `code` of `formatMatches` `function`. Also, is there any specific reason to use `formControlName` and `ngModel` together?

Comment: @developer033,  `formatMatches = (value: any) => value.name || '';`
You're right, `ngModel` isn't needed, but without it the result is still the same.